# R Conditional standard deviation

Tags: r

I have a large data set and I need to get the standard deviation for the `Main` column based on the number of rows in other columns. Here is a sample data set:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  Main = c(0.33, 0.57, 0.60, 0.51), 
  B = c(NA, NA, 0.09,0.19), 
  C = c(NA, 0.05, 0.07, 0.05), 
  D = c(0.23, 0.26, 0.23, 0.26)
)

View(df1)
#   Main    B       C       D  
# 1 0.33    NA      NA      0.23
# 2 0.57    NA      0.05    0.26
# 3 0.60    0.09    0.07    0.23
# 4 0.51    0.19    0.05    0.26
```

Take column `B` as an example, since row 1&2 are `NA`, its standard deviation will be `sd(df1[3:4,1])`; column `C&D` will be `sd(df1[2:4,1])` and `sd(df1[1:4,1])`. Therefore, the result will be:

```
#     B       C       D  
# 1   0.06    0.05    0.12
```

I did the followings but it only returned one number - `0.0636`

```
df2 <- df1[,-1]!=0

sd(df1[df2,1], na.rm = T)
```

My data set has many more columns, and I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to get it done? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
sapply(df1[,-1], function(x) sd(df1[!is.na(x), 1]))

#          B          C          D 
# 0.06363961 0.04582576 0.12093387
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- colnames(df) # list all columns you want to calculate sd of 
value <- sapply(1:length(x) , function(i) sd(df[,x[i],drop=TRUE], na.rm = T))
names(value) <- x

#          Main          B          C          D 
#    0.12093387 0.07071068 0.01154701 0.01732051
```

Answer (score 0):

We can get this with `colSds` from `matrixStats`

```
library(matrixStats)
colSds(`dim<-`(df1[,1][NA^is.na(df1[-1])*row(df1[-1])], dim(df1[,-1])), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 0.06363961 0.04582576 0.12093387
```